# Detecting collision in a 2D environment with Slick

Tags: java, 2d, collision, slick2d

I have been having some trouble detecting the collision in my game. It seems that collision detection only works part of the time on only some of the walls. I am using slick2d for my library. If you need any more code or info I can give it to you. I have to go somewhere right now so I am just typing this out quickly but if you need anything more just ask.

Code:

```
@Override
public void manageWallCollision(Scene currScene) {
    for(int i = 0; i < currScene.getMapManager().getWalls().size(); i++){
    MapTile currTile = currScene.getMapManager().getWalls().get(i);

        if(currTile.isCollidable()){
            if(this.getBounds().intersects(currTile.getBounds())){
                //bottom
                if(this.y2 < currTile.getY()){

                }
                //right
                else if(this.x2 < currTile.getX()){

                }
                //left
                else if(this.y > currTile.getY2()){

                }
                //top
                else if(this.x > currTile.getX()){

                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

New Code:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < currScene.getMapManager().getWalls().size(); i++){
        MapTile currTile = currScene.getMapManager().getWalls().get(i);

        if(currTile.isCollidable()){
            if(this.getBounds().intersects(currTile.getBounds())){
                //down
                if(this.y2 < currTile.getY() && this.y < currTile.getY2() && this.y2 < currTile.getY2()){
                    this.setY(currTile.getY() - this.getHEIGHT());
                }
                //up
                if(this.y < currTile.getY2() && this.y2 > currTile.getY() && this.y2 > currTile.getY2()){
                    this.setY(currTile.getY2());
                }
                //right
                if(this.x2 < currTile.getX() && this.x < currTile.getX2() && this.x2 < currTile.getX2()){
                    this.setX(currTile.getX() - this.getWIDTH());
                }
                //left
                if(this.x < currTile.getX2() && this.x2 > currTile.getX() && this.x2 > currTile.getX2()){
                    this.setX(currTile.getX2());
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

I am still having issues. It detects the collision fine but wherever it hits on a specific wall it goes to the same spot. Imagine a 2d room. So if it collided with the left wall then it automatically goes to a position on that wall. And if you try and slide along the wall then it gets really glitchy and you are constantly moving forward and then backwards. I am confused as to what is happening.